# Where to put a .so in my Java application?

Tags: java, maven, shared-libraries

I have an application I'm writing in Java. A third-party library I'm using comes with a shared-object library that I must distribute to make the consumed JAR code work.

My question is where to put *libacme.so* in my development project in order that it get put inside my JAR in the right place when built by Maven?

I was thinking of *src/main/resources/libacme.so*, but I'd like to know best practice/right way of doing this.

Comment: src/main/resources should be fine

Comment: any place in the class path should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling to get this to work in a JUnit test, calling `System.loadLibrary()`. Once I do that, I wonder if what I did to get it working for JUnit will hold for production.

Comment: If I put _acme.so_ in _src/main/resources_, what's the argument to `loadLibrary()` going to look like? Must I add _resources_ to `java.class.path` in order for this to work (_resources_ isn't already in the list back from `System.getProperty( "java.class.path" or "java.library.path" )`.